# How to calculate Estimated Daily Reach using fb api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I want to show the daily estimated reach using fb api.

I have tried below code :-

```
$ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'facebook');

$url_en = urlencode("{'geo_locations':{'countries': ['US'],},'age_min':20,'age_max':24}");


   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/act_1375199556085956/reachestimate?access_token=ACCESS TOKEN&targeting_spec=".$url_en);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

But getting the response data below :-

```
"data": {
      "users": 14600000,
      "bid_estimations": [
         {
            "unsupported": false,
            "location": 3,
            "cpa_min": 79,
            "cpa_median": 145,
            "cpa_max": 195,
            "cpc_min": 45,
            "cpc_median": 70,
            "cpc_max": 87,
            "cpm_min": 8,
            "cpm_median": 20,
            "cpm_max": 27
         }
      ],
      "estimate_ready": true
   }
}
```

BUT, I want result like:

[image]

Please help me with this.

Comment: Found any answer ? I am also looking for same thing.

Comment: Not yet. I think there is no calculation for it. :(

Comment: yes, looking for an answer as well !!! vote up for the question

Comment: Did someone found the answer? even though its monthly reach, can we get the min/max users?

Answer (score 2):

Added in v2.9

```
/<AD_ACCOUNT>/delivery_estimate
```

or

```
/<AD_SET>/delivery_estimate
```

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/targeting/v2.9

Answer (score 1):

The API only supports monthly estimates according to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reachestimate/v2.5)

Comment: Thanks Elmo. How do you get the range number of users (13000-24000) for the monthly reach? which fields are they in the response?